# SSRS 2008 INTERACTIVE SORT

Tags: reporting-services

I have never done an interactive sort before so I might be missing something basic.

I have a table that lists customers in rows and their various service choices in columns.  I am counting the number of times they used each service.  I want the user to be able to click on the service type and sort the most frequent users of that particular service type.

This current configuration returns an error that "The grouping ‘SERVICE’ has a SortExpression using aggregates without explicit scopes and the SortExpressionScope is omitted"

However, I am not sure if my problem is something else.

Thank you

Comment: This error occurs when you try to apply aggregates to "Details" group instead of manually created group. If you have "Details" group, remove it and recreate manually.

Answer (score 4):

Hi Lance try below thing..
Select "Enable Interactive sorting"-> Groups-> Select Group Name in list -> sort by count(Services).
Hope this helps.
[image]

Comment: That is what I have entered and I am still getting the same error regarding a Sort Expression Scope being ommitted (exact error is above).